# Asp.net Web Site build and Publish

Tags: c#, asp.net, cruisecontrol.net, nant

How to build and publish the ASP.NET web site(Microsoft Vishul Studio->File->New->Website) using Cruise Control.net. 
Actually, ASP.NET Web site doesnot contain .csproj and .sln file.

Please Provide the solution and Suggestion for same.

Thanks in advance....

Answer (score 1):

You can add your web site to an empty solution (giving you a .sln file), then call msbuild.exe using the [exec task](http://nant.sourceforge.net/release/latest/help/tasks/exec.html) against the solution file, or use [NAntContrib's](http://nantcontrib.sourceforge.net/) [msbuild](http://nantcontrib.sourceforge.net/release/latest/help/tasks/msbuild.html) task.

For deploying, since it's a website, you have two options: either [copy](http://nant.sourceforge.net/release/latest/help/tasks/copy.html) the files directly to the target location, or first precompile with [aspnet_compiler.exe](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229863(VS.80).aspx), then copy.  See [this MSDN article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms227976.aspx) on more info on precompiling.

Your build file will contain roughly the following tasks:

1. MsBuild
2. (Optional) aspnet_compile
3. Copy to destination location

Plug that into cruise control and you should be good to go (though I recommend separate build configurations for 1 and 2 vs 3).

Answer (score 0):

please refer the msdn link: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1y1404zt(VS.80).aspx

Comment: thanks anish but i want to build and publish ASP.NET website using criuse control.net and NANT Script instead of Visual Studio UI.